# Angular - How to watch for ngResource values in parent controller scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my angular app, i've got a controller parent child relationship like the one shown below. My parent controller is loading a resource using ngResource and doing some rendering in the view. I'd like to use the resource from the parent scope in my child controller, but because the ngResource call is asynchronous, the ImageUrls value in the scope isn't defined yet. I thought that setting up a watcher in the child controller was the way to go but it hasn't worked.

Does anyone have any idea how to get around this? Thanks!

template.html

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController">    
    <div ng-controller="ChildController">
        <div ng-repeat='img in myResource.ImageUrls'>
           <div ng-show="doShowImg(img)">
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

script.js

```
function ParentController($scope, $routeParams, MyResource) {
    $scope.myResource = MyResource.get({recipeId:$routeParams.recipeId}, function() {
        $scope.imageUrls = $scope.myResource.ImageUrls;
    });
}

function ChildController($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('imageUrls', function(imageUrls) {
        $scope.doShowImg = function(img) {
            if($scope.imageUrls.length = 5) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's worth mentioning that although I'm getting the javascript errors because my value in the scope is undefined, my app is still working. It appears as though the function in the child controller is called, then the resource is loaded, then the repeater is executed and the function is called again on the images in the list.

Comment: The first time watch get trigger the value would be null and you need to handle it. After that on changes the watch would trigger with new and old value. What is the issue you are facing is not very clear.

Comment: Yeah, handling the undefined case definitely works.